# Calculate the areas bounded by the curves: $y=\frac{1}{x^2}e^\frac{1}{x}, y=0, y=1, x =2$

Tags: calculus

**Question**

> Calculate the areas bounded by the curves:  $y=\frac{1}{x^2}e^\frac{1}{x}, y=0, y=1, x =2$

I have little to no experience in finding areas with such curves , I've watched a lot of videos on youtube on this topic, butI couldn't figure out what I can do with it.  I was wondering about your thoughts on it. I'd also be very thankful if someone were to have a complete answer

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Thank you for the remark, I've edited my question

Comment: Hint: Start by graphing the region, then use the "top-minus-bottom" principle. Strong hint: a substitution.

Comment: Susbtitute $u=1/x$.

Comment: Still didn't manage to solve it, but thank you all for a hint

Answer (score 1):

Solving for the lower bound $x$, we have

$$x^2=e^{1/x}\implies x=\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}$$

Where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

The upper bound is still $x=2$. Noting we are between the curve and $y=1$ yields

$$I=2-\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}-\int_{\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}}^2\frac{1}{x^2}e^{1/x}\;dx$$

Let $u=1/x$, $du=-1/x^2\;dx$.

$$\implies I=2-\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}-\int_{1/2}^{2W(1/2)}e^u\;du$$

$$\implies I=2-\frac{1}{2W(1/2)}-\exp(2W(1/2))+\exp(1/2)$$

Comment: Could it be done without Lambert function? By placing the first multiplier under the sign of the differential, so d(1/x)=-dx/x^2

Comment: I don't know much about that integration technique, but my gut says no. If you define $c$ to be the solution to $x^2=e^{1/x}$ and solve symbolically I struggle to see how you'll get around it.

Comment: I've gotta solve it somehow without Lambert function, do you have other ideas?